# TrueNAS as a fast partial copy of a cloud storage

Tags: linux, database, bigdata, storage

I have near unlimited amount of cloud storage (dropbox and/or onedrive) and a ton of data. I cannot store all the data on my computer to I need to up- and download it from the cloud which takes days. So I want to build a system, which can hold some amount as a sort of Cache.

My idea is to use TrueNAS and back everything up from there to the cloud. Then I would like a page where I can select the folders that should remain on the NAS. This will create sync jobs which will run during the night.

Do you know such kind of systems?